# Give a context free grammar for the language

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I need to formulate a context free grammar for $A =\{(ab)^n(ab)^n | n ≥ 1 \}$.

My try:

$S → abS|abT$

$T → abS|ε $

I am not sure if this production is correct. I am new to the subject.

Comment: Did you notice that $A = \{(abab)^n \mid n \geqslant 1\} = (abab)^+$ ?

Comment: Your grammar allows the derivation $S\Rightarrow abT\Rightarrow ab$, and $ab\notin A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $S \rightarrow abTab$ as your start rule, and make the rule for $T$ very similar, only that $T$ needs to be able to terminate the derivation.